# Let X and Y be independent standard normal random variables. Find the density function of Z = max(X, Y) and use it to find the expectation of Z.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X \& Y$ are independent standard normal variables:
$P(X\cap Y)=P(X)P(Y)$ and their respective densities are = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}$.
How do I go about converting this into the density of $max(X,Y)?$ I'm not too sure how to progress my working into the new function.

Comment: What mean $P(X)$ or $P(X\cap Y)$ ? For your question, notice that $$\mathbb P\{\max(X,Y)\leq z\}=\mathbb P\{X\leq z,Y\leq z\}.$$

Comment: If $X$  $Y$ are independent *events* then $P(X\cap Y)=P(X)P(Y)$

Comment: @Henry I said that at the beginning, thank you for the help nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not too sure how to progress my working into the new function.

$$f_Z(z)=2\phi(z)\Phi(z)$$

where $\phi$ is the standard normal density and $\Phi$ is its CDF

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, the density and distribution functions be the same as they are for both X and Y? As in is ϕ written as I have in my question, and Φ= the integral between -infinity and x of ϕ?

Comment: @user843361 yes

Comment: I think I've figured out what I was looking for thanks to you, would the expected value of Z therefore be the integral this function multiplied by z?